# subgroup of $p$-group is a subset of center

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Show that in a  group $G$ of order $p^2$ any normal subgroup of order $p$ must lie in the center of $G$.

**Remark:** I have found the solution of this problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318579/normal-subgroup-of-order-p-is-in-the-center) with elegant solution given by Jyrki Lahtonen. Initially I was trying to solve it by myself but my efforts were unsuccessful. Can anyone help to complete my solution?

**Proof:** Suppose that $N$ normal subgroup in $G$ and $o(N)=p$ $\Rightarrow$ $N$ - cyclic group $\Rightarrow$ $N$ - abelian group. Then $G/N$ group which has $\frac{o(G)}{o(N)}=\frac{p^2}{p}=p$ elements $\Rightarrow$ $G/N$-cyclic. Suppose that $G/N= \langle N\hat{g}\rangle$ then $(N\hat{g})^p=N\hat{g}^p=N$ then $\hat{g}^p\in N$.

Let $n\in N$ and $g\in G$. Since $Ng\in G/N$ then $Ng=(N\hat{g})^k=N\hat{g}^k$ for some $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. So $g=n_1\hat{g}^k$. Thus $$ng=nn_1\hat{g}^k=n_1n\hat{g}^k=?$$

Is it possible to derive that it is equal to $gn$? If $\hat{g}^k\in N$ then OK.
I have tried many ways but no results :(

Comment: Actually, more is true: any group of order $p^2$ is abelian

Comment: FYI, a more general statement is also true: if $G$ is any finite group and $p$ is the smallest prime dividing $|G|$, then any normal subgroup of order $p$ must be contained in $Z(G)$. The [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1764556/169852) is pretty straightforward if you know a bit about group actions.

Answer (score 1):

I followed your way of proof and completed it as follows. Since $G/N$ and $N$ are cyclic, we may assume that $G/N=\langle\overline g\rangle$ and $N=\langle x\rangle$ for some $g\in G$ and $x\in N$. Now that $\overline g^p=N$, it follows $g^p=x^k$ for some $1\leqslant k\leqslant p$. If $k<p$, then $x^k$ is also a generator of $N$ and thus $x=g^{pm}$ for some integer $m$, by which $gx=xg$ is obvious and hence $N\leqslant Z(G)$. If $k=p$, then $\langle g\rangle$ is also a subgroup of order $p$, while
$$
|\langle g\rangle\langle x\rangle|=\frac{|\langle g\rangle||\langle x\rangle|}{|\langle g\rangle\cap\langle x\rangle|}=p^2\text{ or }p
$$
entails that either $G=\langle g\rangle\times\langle x\rangle$ or $\langle g\rangle=\langle x\rangle=\langle g\rangle\langle x\rangle$, i.e., either $G$ is abelian or $gx=xg$, both of which imply that $N\leqslant Z(G)$.

ps. Actually it suffices to consider simply $\langle g\rangle\langle x\rangle$ and the proof will be much easier.

---

There is another way like this, which seems more succinct. Consider $N\cap Z(G)$. Since $Z(G)$ is nontrivial, and
$$
|NZ(G)|=\frac{|N||Z(G)|}{|N\cap Z(G)|}=p\text{ or }p^2,
$$
If it equals to $p$, then $N\leqslant Z(G)$. If it equals to $p^2$, then either $N\leqslant Z(G)$ and $Z(G)=G$, or $|N\cap Z(G)|=1$. For the latter case, adopting a similar treatment, we get $N\leqslant Z(G)$, which leads to a contradiction.

---

As is commented by 57Jimmy, $G$ is actually abelian. This is because $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic in this case, while the center of a $p$-group is non-trivial and $Z(G)$ must be a normal subgroup of order $p$ or $p^2$.

Comment: Thanks but in the last moment you have used direct product which I do not know still :(

Comment: @RFZ It is just a matter of notation for this answer:), which can be avoided. $G$ is the inner direct product of two normal subgroups $H$ and $K$ iff $G=HK$ and $H\cap K=\{e\}$. For the case of $|\langle g\rangle\langle x\rangle|=p^2$, just think about $g^{-1}x^{-1}gx$: it belongs to $\langle g\rangle$ because $x^{-1}gx\in\langle g\rangle$; for a similar reason it also belongs to $\langle x\rangle$. While $\langle g\rangle\cap\langle x\rangle=\{e\}$, you'll see $g^{-1}x^{-1}gx=e$, which is $gx=xg$.

Comment: @RFZ And it is worth noting that, even we don't know $G$ is abelian, we can see that there are normal subgroups of order $p$, and actually any subgroup of order $p$ is normal in this $G$. Think about the normalizer $N_G(H)$ of a subgroup $H$ of order $p$. The only cases are $N_G(H)=H$ or $G$, due to Lagrange theorem. If $N_G(H)=H$ (i.e., $H$ not normal), since the center $Z(G)\leqslant N_G(H)$ is nontrivial, we have $Z(G)=N_G(H)$ because of their orders. Then a contradiction arises that $H=Z(G)$, a normal subgroup of $G$.